# Wifi Error when turning on

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix the WiFi button or prevent WiFi errors when turning it off and back on?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4504/how-can-i-fix-the-wifi-button-or-prevent-wifi-errors-when-turning-it-off-and-back)

After I turn on my phone (a Samsung Galaxy I551) the wifi works great. After some times of turning it on and off it gets screwed and when I try to turn it on it displays "Error", without any further specifications. I found a lot in some forums but I couldn't really get any solution.

It is really annoying because I generally don't turn off my phone so now I have to reboot it frequently.

I can't relate this with the opening of some app or something like that :(

Thanks for any help!

Diego

Comment: Unfortunately the dupe doesn't have a good workaround, hopefully someone figures it out eventually.

Comment: It's not duplicated. For me once it showed Error message, I can't turn it on again until reboot, not even from Settings

Comment: I've had that happen before too.  I'll update my question.

Comment: I've finally found a workaround to this issue (which ALWAYS required me to do a restart). See here: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/56206/4336